# Is the SharePoint publishing cache flushed on server restart?

Tags: blob-cache

If I restart the SharePoint server will the publishing cache be flushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. It is only flushed by manually doing so.

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "<WebApplicationURL>"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)
Write-Host "Flushed the BLOB cache for:" $webApp
```